# Spark - limit to 1 task per worker

Tags: apache-spark

Is there a way to limit Spark to launching only 1 task on each worker using Spark's standalone cluster manager? I'd like to run a job which accesses an external resource and have a way to rate limit it.

[image]

Comment: Curious to as why you would want to do that?

Comment: I want to access an external resource from within the job and want to be able to rate-limit access to that resource

Comment: Which cluster manager?

Comment: It's one executor per worker node till 1.5 release. Have a look at : https://issues.apache.org/jira/plugins/servlet/mobile#issue/SPARK-1706. Set SPARK_WORKER_INSTANCES in spark-env.sh as 1 in worker node.

Comment: @JustinPihony Spark's standalone cluster manager